# Can node.js be integrated with php?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

is that even a good idea for scaling heavy php apps ? for example, how does node's mysql module compare to php's mysqli extension in terms of performance etc ..

Comment: No. Re-write your PHP app in js.

Answer (score 2):

I'd seriously consider wrapping your PHP app with node.js; that is, having a migration path of your existing PHP being called by your node code, eventually migrating the PHP code into Javascript.  The reason being, the execution model of node.js (non-blocking) doesn't really play well with PHP's execution model.  That said, the execution models can be made more compatible with a wrapping approach; that is, having node be your exposed server, and making appropriate PHP calls (re-request); you can likely use that process to "migrate" your "wrapped" PHP over to a node server, then slowly migrate your PHP code to node.

Of course, this begs the question of whether or not you really even need / want to do this, but that's for you to determine...

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty good mysql libraries available in node.js with okay performance, but I would just rewrite(because you will still have to do a lot of coding when you use mysql libraries) the slow parts in node.js using redis or mongodb and just keep the rest in PHP. Especially redis with node_redis(hiredis) is very fast. You can use [NGinx to do the proxing](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/04/nginx-php-fpm-and-node-js-install-on-centos-5-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Output the result or data fetch from mysql via Nodejs is better than via LAMP.